# Glassfish 4 JDBC Resource connection fails with Hibernate 4.3.5 and JPA 2.1 connection allocation refused due to database "null"

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc, glassfish, jta

I'm quite new to Java EE, and I have set up a project using NetBeans 8.0. In my EAR project, I created a JDBC DataSource and ConnectionPool which are successfully deployed to the Glassfish server upon deployment.

When I try to connect I am using JPA 2.1 with Hibernate 4.3.5 and I am using the JTA `jta-data-source` entry in my `persistence.xml` file to name the managed resource.

My `persistence.xml` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" 
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd
        ">
    <persistence-unit name="my_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDatasource</jta-data-source>
        <class>my.domain.model.MyModel</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="jdbc/myDatasource" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I try to deploy the project, everything goes well until the Hibernate hbm2ddl kicks in, and the following error message appears:

```
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
[...]
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
            name: my_PU
            ...]
INFO:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
INFO:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO:   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
WARN:   HHH000193: Overriding hibernate.transaction.factory_class is dangerous, this might break the EJB3 specification implementation
INFO:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
WARNING:   RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool myConnectionPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
WARNING:   RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ myConnectionPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
WARNING:   RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist]
WARN:   HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
INFO:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
INFO:   HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
INFO:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO:   HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
INFO:   HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
WARNING:   RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool myConnectionPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
WARNING:   RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ myConnectionPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
WARNING:   RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist]
ERROR:   HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:150)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:239)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:431)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:114)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:129)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "null" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:572)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:177)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:95)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:78)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:115)
    ... 79 more

...
```

Comment: I'm assuming the `hibernate.properties not found` isn't relevant as it looks like it's picked up the properties from the `persistence.xml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something is fundamentally wrong with the configuration of your connection pool within Glassfish.

Go check the properties etc., and make sure you can PING the DB from the Admin Console.

Comment: Perfect, after rummaging around for a bit, I found that it was the way that NetBeans created the details for the deployed JDBC Connection Pool. The `jdbc-connection-pool` element of the `sun-resources.xml` in my parent project contained 3 properties; The server URL, Username and Password. These are not all used, and the connection seems to look for separate properties, namely the `ServerName`, `PortNumber`, `DatabaseName`, `User`, and `Password` and creates the URL itself. Many thanks Will!

Answer (score 0):

This guidance is for integrating hibernate.4.3.5 and EJB and GlassFish.4.0 in NetBeans.8.0 IDE.
Create a web project in net beans and add hibernate jar files to the project,other setting related to configuring MySql and  glassfish is very simple so I do not describe in this article then create persistence.xml file as follow :

```
<persistence-unit name="omidashouriPU" transaction-type="Resource_Local">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YourSchemaName"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="yourpassword"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

In Your EJB class (class that annotated with @Stateless) for creating EntityManager use following syntax :

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("omidashouriPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(YourEntityObject);
em.getTransaction().end();
```

As you Know when you are using “transaction-type="Resource_Local", you have to manage the transaction by yourself, mean that, managing of opening and closing the transaction is our responsibility.