# Glassfish can't connect to a mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Im on my wits end currently after a day spent on this. Whenever I deploy my app I get the error that is at the end of this post. I've created proper datasource in glassfish console (when pinged it works). I've put both mysql connector and hibernate in glassfish libs. I have no idea what else I can do. Mysql database works.

Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="testPersist" transaction-type="JTA">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <jta-data-source>jdbc/test</jta-data-source>

            <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Error:

```
2015-03-01T20:15:44.668+0100|WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
2015-03-01T20:15:44.684+0100|Info: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: testPersist
    ...]
2015-03-01T20:15:44.777+0100|Info: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
2015-03-01T20:15:44.777+0100|Info: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.service.allow_crawling=false, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
2015-03-01T20:15:44.777+0100|Info: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-03-01T20:15:44.995+0100|Info: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-03-01T20:15:45.057+0100|Warning: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ MysqlTest ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException
2015-03-01T20:15:45.057+0100|Warning: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null]
2015-03-01T20:15:45.057+0100|WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
2015-03-01T20:15:45.073+0100|Info: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2015-03-01T20:15:45.073+0100|Info: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2015-03-01T20:15:45.182+0100|Info: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-03-01T20:15:45.542+0100|Info: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2015-03-01T20:15:45.542+0100|Info: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2015-03-01T20:15:45.542+0100|Warning: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ MysqlTest ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException
2015-03-01T20:15:45.542+0100|Warning: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null]
2015-03-01T20:15:45.542+0100|ERROR: HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:146)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.gjc.util.SecurityUtils.getPasswordCredential(SecurityUtils.java:119)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 74 more

2015-03-01T20:15:45.542+0100|ERROR: HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:146)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.gjc.util.SecurityUtils.getPasswordCredential(SecurityUtils.java:119)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 74 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add some properties in the pressistant.xml file, that why the connection can't be established from you IDE and mySQL Database. 
add:

`<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDatabaseName"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>`

Check this link [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858226/glassfish-4-jdbc-resource-connection-fails-with-hibernate-4-3-5-and-jpa-2-1-conn/)